# Convert ICollection<T> to List<T>

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert ICollection to List using below code-

```
ICollection<DataStructure> list_Stuctures = dataConnectorService.ListStructures(dataConnector, SupportedDataStructures.All);

List<DataStructure> lst_DataStructure = new List<DataStructure>();

list_Stuctures.CopyTo(lst_DataStructure);
```

On last line, I get below exception-

> Exception = TargetParameterCountException
>
> Message = Parameter count mismatch.

How to convert ICollection to List?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The easiest way to convert a `ICollection` to a `List` is the usage of LINQ like ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx))

```
List<T> L = C.ToList();
```

Dont't forget to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

otherwise `ToList()` is not available.

Comment: I have a `SortedList`. I want to get the Keys as a `List<string>`, but the `ICollection.ToList()` method is not recognized, even though the `System.Linq` assembly has been referenced. My project is targeting the .NET 4.8 framework.

Answer (score 6):

You can supply the collection as an argument in the `List<T>` constructor:

```
List<DataStructure> lst_DataStructure = new List<DataStructure>(list_Stuctures);
```

Or use the `.ToList()` extension method, which does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple, [ToList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<DataStructure> lst_DataStructure = list_Stuctures.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the recommendations worked for me. I'm a bit surprised to not see this pretty obvious answer. At least it seems obvious to me after looking through other attempts. This may be a tab bit longer in some cases, but perhaps worth it for performance and peace of mind?

What do you guys think?

## For context

I am working with two different types.

*In my case both share the same underlying classes (Integrations are fun I guess).*

PLAY - https://dotnetfiddle.net/oTa4Dt#

```
/// One is ---------- | ---- ICollection<T>
/// The other is ---- | ---- List<PreferencesResponse>

ICollection<T> result = default!;

var myPreferences = new List<PreferencesResponse>();
foreach (var preference in result.Result.ToList())
{
    var preferencesResponse = new PreferencesResponse()
    {
        Id = preference.Id,
        Status = preference.Status,
        StatusDescription = preference.StatusDescription,
        Priority = preference.Priority
    };
    mySupplierPreferences.Add(preferencesResponse);
}
returnValue = new Response(true, mySupplierPreferences);
```

Are there any reasons you can think of that this wouldn't be correct or at least - most correct?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do that for me was the following:

```
var array = Array.Empty<string>();
parameters.Keys.CopyTo(array, 0);
```

Answer (score -2):

Because ICollection implement IEnumerable you can use a foreach.

```
foreach(var item in list_Stuctures) 
{
  lst_DataStructure.ADD(item);
}
```