# How to convert ICollection<ICollection<int>> to List<List<int>> in C#

Tags: c#

Is there any way to elegantly do this? All I need to do is store a new variable `List<List<int>>` with values of another array `ICollection<ICollection<int>>`, but I can't find any way to do this.

The code:

```
ICollection<ICollection<int>> mycollection = // instantiate with some numbers
List<List<int>> myList = myCollection;
```

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Example has been edited in.

Comment: Are the collections actually lists?

Comment: @Blindy Uhm.. They are ICollection's.. Could you elaborate and give an example if they were lists?

Comment: They can't be `ICollection`, that's an interface you can't instantiate. They have to be something else, what are they?

Comment: @HimBromBeere They come in a model from a Python program.

Comment: It doesn't matter where they're coming from, I'm asking you what are they? You have reflection for a reason, use it and tell us. `mycollection.GetType().Name` is what I want to know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert ICollection<T> to List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189795/convert-icollectiont-to-listt)

Comment: @Blindy It gives me List`1 . And that is using GetType().Name

Comment: So it's a `List<>` already, as I suspected. @hisbrombeere got you covered!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have an extension-method for this kind of problem, that first tries to cast the collection into a list to prevent obsolete calls to `ToList`:

```
public static List<T> SafeToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var list = source as List<T>;
    return list ?? source.ToList();
}
```

Now you can use the following:

```
var result = myCollectionOfCollections.Select(x => x.SafeToList()).SafeToList();
```

Be aware, though, that if a client calls `Add` or `Remove` or even `Clear` on te returned collection, this will alter the original collection if this already is a list. If it is any different type of collection - say a `HastSet<T>`- manipulating the returned collection won't change the original one.

If your collections may be arrays and you do not focus on `List<T>` as outcome of the method you can also use the more generic interface `IList<T>` instead:

```
public static IList<T> SafeToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var list = source as List<T>;
    var array = source as T[];
    return list ?? array ?? source.ToList();
}
```

or as one-liner:

```
public static IList<T> SafeToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    => source as List<T> ?? source as T[] ?? (IList<T>) source.ToList();
```

Comment: This is much better, unless the source is an array in which case you should do something similar and return arrays of arrays instead.

Comment: @Blindy My actual extension-method also handles arrays. But OP literally asks for `List<T>`.

Comment: @Orace thanks for the edits. I would vote for them, if this was possible.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I fixed some typos, also with new fancy capability of C#, one can write `return source is List<T> list ? list : source.ToList();`

Comment: The downside to this approach is that it either creates a new list or returns the existing list after the cast. That means if the caller modifies the result then they may be modifying the original sequence or not, depending on the input types.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Linq:

```
ICollection<ICollection<int>> data = ...;        
var converted = data.Select(c => c.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: @Blindy And it´s the only way unless the collections already **are** lists

Comment: Which is why I asked the OP if they are, rather than directly going for the nuclear option!

Comment: a "slightly" more efficient way would be to use the list's constructor that supports numerables. `var converted = new List(data.Select(c => new List(c)));`

Comment: It's not more efficient, it's the same code. You still allocate many lists, and you still copy the data of every single list over.

Comment: There's nothing correct about copying nested lists and putting pressure on the GC unnecessarily. And it's "answer", not "answers". The other answer is correct and I upvoted that.

Comment: @Blindy - You do realize that the other answer is buggy, right..?

Comment: @Blindy - In the other example, if you call `Clear` on the items in the returned list then it may delete the contents of the original `ICollection` if that collection is actually a list, but is the original `ICollection` was something else (such as a Hashset<int>) then it won't change the original. That's a subtle bug that's waiting to happen.